# Plotting 3D plot with cross-correlation and different marker sizes to show N

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, plot, plotly

I have a dataframe like this:

[image]

```
data = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 3], [1, 1, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 3, 2], [2, 3, 3], [1, 1, 1], [3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 2], [1, 2, 1], [1, 3, 1], [3, 1, 3], [2, 1, 2], [3, 3, 3], [2, 2, 2], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 2], [2, 2, 1], [1, 1, 3], [1, 3, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Math', 'Science', 'English'])
```

Where each row depicts a student. The ratings 1-3 are as follows:
1 is Poor grade,
2 is Average grade,
3 is Good grade

What I'm interested in doing is to create a 3D plot that shows correlation between a student's grades and also shows N (number).

I'm not sure if the subjects should be on the x y z axis, or their grade (would like to try both).  Instead of just a 3D scatter plot, I'll like markers in the same place (for example, a student who has 3 (good grade) in all 3 categories) to be bigger to show the N. Essentially, I'll like the size of the marker to show the N, and either their grade or subject (or both) to be colour-coded.

Is there a way to visualize this type of data in a clear manner? I was thinking of something like a 3D venn diagram, but I cannot figure it out. I tried using multi-hierarchy circlify but couldn't achieve a 3D aspect, where it cross-correlates both grades and subjects. Any guidance will be super appreciated!

edit: N values for this sample dataframe:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why do you want a student with a higher `N` to have a larger marker – does `N` mean anything in the context of your data? And although you could create a 3d scatter plot, this data is categorical in all dimensions, so you would need to use jittering to avoid overlapping points. I would just point out that although there might be some clustering (let's say students are more likely to do poor or well in all classes), there are only 27 possible combinations of grades and visually the points will all be relatively close together, but i'd be happy to write up a 3d scatter with some sample data

Comment: @DerekO Hi Derek, thanks for commenting! I want a larger marker to show N because the "size" of the groups is very important for us - we're looking at trends. I tried a scatter plot earlier but didn't know about jittering!! My concern with scatter plots is that the clustered points won't look that clear re: size per group, so a bigger marker would make it more obvious - but would be super grateful to see what you come up with! Thanks again!

Comment: can you include the `N` values for this particular sample dataframe? that would be helpful!

Comment: @DerekO Yes, I've updated the post! Let me know if you were referring to something else!!

Comment: i was thinking more along the lines of a dataframe in the format of the `df` that you posted with another column for `N` but if not, that's not too difficult of a fix. your edit does clarify what N means though, thanks!

Comment: @DerekO oh yes, by N i mean number - therefore for groups with higher number of students, i wanted a bigger marker (i just realized this sample dataframe might not be the best to show this, oops!)

sorry about that, im away from my computer now so i don't think i can add that in, hope thats ok!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created some sample data with the same format as yours with 200 students having ratings of 1-3 occuring pseudo-randomly (but with a higher proportion of 2's and 3's so that we can see a pattern).

Additional edits: (1) you can use a mapping to replace the ratings `1,2,3` with `"poor", "average","good"` in the `df` itself, and plotly will understand this is meant to be categorical data and reflect this in the axes on the 3d scatter and (2) to color the markers in a consistent way, we need to combine the ratings from the subjects – the most straightforward way is to create a new column "sum" that is the sum of ratings from all three subjects, and pass the name of this column to `px.scatter_3d`

And you can remove the information about `count` from the hovertemplate using the following: : `fig.update_traces(hovertemplate="Math=%{x}<br>Science=%{y}<br>English=%{z}<br>sum=%{marker.color}<extra></extra>")`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

## create some random data where there will be clusters
np.random.seed(42)
data = np.random.choice([1,2,3],size=[200,3], p=[0.2,0.3,0.5])
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Math', 'Science', 'English'])

rating_map = {1: 'poor', 2: 'average', 3:'good'}

## count the number of times each unique combination of grades occurs
df_counts = df.value_counts().rename('counts').reset_index()
df_counts['sum'] = df_counts['Math'] + df_counts['Science'] + df_counts['English']
df_counts[['Math','Science','English']] = df_counts[['Math','Science','English']].applymap(lambda x: rating_map[x])

fig = px.scatter_3d(df_counts, x='Math', y='Science', z='English', size='counts', size_max=50, color='sum')
fig.update_layout(coloraxis_colorbar=dict(
    title="Combined Rating",
    tickvals=[3,6,9],
    ticktext=["Poor", "Average", "Good"],
))

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Gosh this is SO cool! I had a few questions if you don't mind: 1. is it possible to remove the numbered axes and relabel them with the actual type of grades? (e.g. poor instead of 1, good instead of 3). 2. alternatively (or in combo, if possible), is it possible to colour code? for example, dividing the "walls" into 3 sections, red for poor, blue for average, green for good. my dataset has 18 combinations out of 27 and the still image is very difficult to understand - but I'm not familiar with plotly so i'm all ears to other edits if these aren't actually possible!! THANK YOU!

Comment: I added the html of your plot, feel free to steal if if you'd like~

Comment: 1. this can definitely be done with a mapping, 2. i'm a little unclear on what you mean by walls because if we add a plane corresponding to "poor" for one of the categories, it will go through all 3 sections of the other categories.

Comment: @DerekO 1. Great!! and for 2., I meant the grey (?) squared "walls", so splitting it up into 3 colours according to the numbered axes? And/or colouring the markers with some sort of gradient? Thanks again for all your guidance!!

Comment: oh i see what you mean – the "walls" are part of the default grid used in all plotly scatter plots. you could consider adding planes, but there would be 9 total which i honestly think would make the plot more confusing. coloring the markers isn't trivial because you have contributions from each subject– would you consider coloring the markers by the sum of the ratings? this "loses" a little information because a student with `3+1+1` is colored the same as `2+2+1`, but it gives us a consistent way to color the markers (and the 3 categories are on the axes anyway)

Comment: @DerekO Sorry for the late reply, had to step away for a moment! This was exactly what I meant, wow!!! The sum idea is wonderful even if we lose information - I think it'll be too confusing otherwise with 18 combos. Just one small thing - is it possible to change the colour legend on the side (3-9 numbers) to something like "overall poor, average, good" as well? Once again, thank you so much for all the help!

Comment: @Serena thanks for accepting the answer– and yes you can change the tick text for the color bar. i've updated the answer accordingly

Comment: @DerekO Thank you SO much again, I really feel like I learnt so much from you!! One last follow-up question (sorry!!), what are the labels that pop up after you hover over a marker called? And is it possible to edit them (for example, if I want to remove counts?) I keep googling but I can't seem to figure out what the term is. Thanks again!!!!

Comment: @Serena no worries – glad to have helped! plotly calls it a `hovertemplate` and for your problem, you can probably modify the hovertemplate using something like `fig.update_traces(hovertemplate="Math=%{x}<br>Science=%{y}<br>English=%{z}<br>sum=%{marker.color}<extra></extra>")`. it's definitely tricky because you have to use the names of the variables that plotly accesses internally mixed together with html tags. the documentation [here](https://plotly.com/python/hover-text-and-formatting/#modifying-the-hovertemplate-of-a-plotly-express-figure) provides a short summary

Answer (score 2):

Check out Derek's Visualization live, use "Run code snippet" and then hit "Full page"~

Produced by doing:

```
print(fig.to_html(default_width=600, 
                  default_height=600, 
                  include_plotlyjs='cdn'))
```

```html
<html>
<head><meta charset="utf-8" /></head>
<body>
    <div>                        <script type="text/javascript">window.PlotlyConfig = {MathJaxConfig: 'local'};</script>
        <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.12.1.min.js"></script>                <div id="a6e33e0b-a196-46ad-87c5-a6c903f4cfcd" class="plotly-graph-div" style="height:600px; width:600px;"></div>            <script type="text/javascript">                                    window.PLOTLYENV=window.PLOTLYENV || {};                                    if (document.getElementById("a6e33e0b-a196-46ad-87c5-a6c903f4cfcd")) {                    Plotly.newPlot(                        "a6e33e0b-a196-46ad-87c5-a6c903f4cfcd",                        [{"hovertemplate":"Math=%{x}<br>Science=%{y}<br>English=%{z}<br>counts=%{marker.size}<extra></extra>","legendgroup":"","marker":{"color":"#636efa","size":[32,17,12,11,10,10,10,9,8,8,8,7,7,7,6,5,5,4,4,4,4,3,3,2,2,1,1],"sizemode":"area","sizeref":0.0128,"symbol":"circle"},"mode":"markers","name":"","scene":"scene","showlegend":false,"x":[3,3,1,3,3,3,2,3,2,2,2,3,2,3,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1],"y":[3,3,3,3,2,2,3,1,1,2,3,1,3,2,3,2,2,1,1,3,1,1,1,2,2,1,2],"z":[3,2,3,1,3,1,3,3,3,3,1,1,2,2,2,3,2,2,1,1,3,2,1,1,2,2,1],"type":"scatter3d"}],                        {"template":{"data":{"histogram2dcontour":[{"type":"histogram2dcontour","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""},"colorscale":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]]}],"choropleth":[{"type":"choropleth","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}],"histogram2d":[{"type":"histogram2d","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""},"colorscale":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]]}],"heatmap":[{"type":"heatmap","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""},"colorscale":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]]}],"heatmapgl":[{"type":"heatmapgl","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""},"colorscale":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]]}],"contourcarpet":[{"type":"contourcarpet","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}],"contour":[{"type":"contour","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""},"colorscale":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]]}],"surface":[{"type":"surface","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""},"colorscale":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]]}],"mesh3d":[{"type":"mesh3d","colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}],"scatter":[{"fillpattern":{"fillmode":"overlay","size":10,"solidity":0.2},"type":"scatter"}],"parcoords":[{"type":"parcoords","line":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"scatterpolargl":[{"type":"scatterpolargl","marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"bar":[{"error_x":{"color":"#2a3f5f"},"error_y":{"color":"#2a3f5f"},"marker":{"line":{"color":"#E5ECF6","width":0.5},"pattern":{"fillmode":"overlay","size":10,"solidity":0.2}},"type":"bar"}],"scattergeo":[{"type":"scattergeo","marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"scatterpolar":[{"type":"scatterpolar","marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"histogram":[{"marker":{"pattern":{"fillmode":"overlay","size":10,"solidity":0.2}},"type":"histogram"}],"scattergl":[{"type":"scattergl","marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"scatter3d":[{"type":"scatter3d","line":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}},"marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"scattermapbox":[{"type":"scattermapbox","marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"scatterternary":[{"type":"scatterternary","marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"scattercarpet":[{"type":"scattercarpet","marker":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}}}],"carpet":[{"aaxis":{"endlinecolor":"#2a3f5f","gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","minorgridcolor":"white","startlinecolor":"#2a3f5f"},"baxis":{"endlinecolor":"#2a3f5f","gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","minorgridcolor":"white","startlinecolor":"#2a3f5f"},"type":"carpet"}],"table":[{"cells":{"fill":{"color":"#EBF0F8"},"line":{"color":"white"}},"header":{"fill":{"color":"#C8D4E3"},"line":{"color":"white"}},"type":"table"}],"barpolar":[{"marker":{"line":{"color":"#E5ECF6","width":0.5},"pattern":{"fillmode":"overlay","size":10,"solidity":0.2}},"type":"barpolar"}],"pie":[{"automargin":true,"type":"pie"}]},"layout":{"autotypenumbers":"strict","colorway":["#636efa","#EF553B","#00cc96","#ab63fa","#FFA15A","#19d3f3","#FF6692","#B6E880","#FF97FF","#FECB52"],"font":{"color":"#2a3f5f"},"hovermode":"closest","hoverlabel":{"align":"left"},"paper_bgcolor":"white","plot_bgcolor":"#E5ECF6","polar":{"bgcolor":"#E5ECF6","angularaxis":{"gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","ticks":""},"radialaxis":{"gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","ticks":""}},"ternary":{"bgcolor":"#E5ECF6","aaxis":{"gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","ticks":""},"baxis":{"gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","ticks":""},"caxis":{"gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","ticks":""}},"coloraxis":{"colorbar":{"outlinewidth":0,"ticks":""}},"colorscale":{"sequential":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]],"sequentialminus":[[0.0,"#0d0887"],[0.1111111111111111,"#46039f"],[0.2222222222222222,"#7201a8"],[0.3333333333333333,"#9c179e"],[0.4444444444444444,"#bd3786"],[0.5555555555555556,"#d8576b"],[0.6666666666666666,"#ed7953"],[0.7777777777777778,"#fb9f3a"],[0.8888888888888888,"#fdca26"],[1.0,"#f0f921"]],"diverging":[[0,"#8e0152"],[0.1,"#c51b7d"],[0.2,"#de77ae"],[0.3,"#f1b6da"],[0.4,"#fde0ef"],[0.5,"#f7f7f7"],[0.6,"#e6f5d0"],[0.7,"#b8e186"],[0.8,"#7fbc41"],[0.9,"#4d9221"],[1,"#276419"]]},"xaxis":{"gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","ticks":"","title":{"standoff":15},"zerolinecolor":"white","automargin":true,"zerolinewidth":2},"yaxis":{"gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","ticks":"","title":{"standoff":15},"zerolinecolor":"white","automargin":true,"zerolinewidth":2},"scene":{"xaxis":{"backgroundcolor":"#E5ECF6","gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","showbackground":true,"ticks":"","zerolinecolor":"white","gridwidth":2},"yaxis":{"backgroundcolor":"#E5ECF6","gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","showbackground":true,"ticks":"","zerolinecolor":"white","gridwidth":2},"zaxis":{"backgroundcolor":"#E5ECF6","gridcolor":"white","linecolor":"white","showbackground":true,"ticks":"","zerolinecolor":"white","gridwidth":2}},"shapedefaults":{"line":{"color":"#2a3f5f"}},"annotationdefaults":{"arrowcolor":"#2a3f5f","arrowhead":0,"arrowwidth":1},"geo":{"bgcolor":"white","landcolor":"#E5ECF6","subunitcolor":"white","showland":true,"showlakes":true,"lakecolor":"white"},"title":{"x":0.05},"mapbox":{"style":"light"}}},"scene":{"domain":{"x":[0.0,1.0],"y":[0.0,1.0]},"xaxis":{"title":{"text":"Math"}},"yaxis":{"title":{"text":"Science"}},"zaxis":{"title":{"text":"English"}}},"legend":{"tracegroupgap":0,"itemsizing":"constant"},"margin":{"t":60}},                        {"responsive": true}                    )                };                            </script>        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: oh thanks! i've been adding gifs to my answers that include plotly visualizations, but this is a great way to add the html directly into answers